# In S3 Bucket , Move large number of files in one folder into multiple folder

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Currently, I have 30 Million files in one folder in an S3 bucket
I want to move 7.5 million files from it into 4 folders in an S3 bucket

I tried out with the AWS CLI command but no idea how to mention the number of files in it

`aws s3 mv s3://BUCKETNAME/myfolder/ s3://BUCKETNAME/folder1/ --recursive`

How can I loop and move only 7.5 million files into each folder?

```
import boto3

aws_access_key_id = ""
aws_secret_access_key = ""
bucket_from = ""
bucket_to = ""
s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key
)
src = s3.Bucket(bucket_from)

def move_files():
    for archive in src.objects.all():

        s3.meta.client.copy_object(
            ACL='public-read',
            Bucket=bucket_to,
            CopySource={'Bucket': bucket_from, 'Key': archive.key},
            Key=archive.key
        )

move_files()
```

Comment: To be clear, you're looking to increase the verbosity of the command-line output so that it displays the total number of files moved?

Comment: No I want to move split 30Millions files into 7.5 files into each folder in automatic way  with aws cli or python

Comment: You will need to 'move' each file individually. Or, write a program (eg in Python) that 'moves' files by copying them to a new Key and then deleting the original files.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes but i am trying to figure out how to move only 7.5 files in python

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

**1. Obtain object listing using Amazon S3 Inventory**

Listing millions of objects can take a long time. Instead, use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects.

This will provide you with a definitive list of current objects.

**2. Split into 4 lists**

Use a text editor to split the file list into 4 separate files -- one for each of your destination folders.

**3. Use Amazon S3 Batch Operations to copy objects**

Copying millions of objects would take a *long* time unless you multi-thread the process.

The easier and faster method would be to [Perform large-scale batch operations on Amazon S3 objects using S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops.html). It can take the S3 Inventory file as input and then perform all the copy operations for you in parallel.

[image: S3 Batch Operations]

**4. Clean-up**

I recommend that you **do not delete the source files** until you are sure that all the copying was done correctly. You can again use **S3 Inventory** to obtain a list for comparison purposes.

Once you want to delete the source files, you can use **S3 Lifecycle** to delete the original objects. **Be very careful** that you do not delete the copied objects at the same time!! For this reason alone it might be better to copy the objects to a *different bucket* from the source files.

Comment: Using s3 Batch can i specify number of files to move ?

Comment: No, you must **provide a list of the specific files to copy**. (Note that it can 'copy', but cannot 'move'.)